# Setting thread pool name for Spring tasks

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a fairly standard Spring 3.2 application with some tasks. In my applicationContext.xml I have

```
<task:annotation-driven/>
```

I also have some methods annotated with `@Scheduled` in the code. I'd like to give a name to the thread pools used by Spring, to simplify the log analysis. Is there any reasonably simple way to do this?
Thanks.

*Update*: Working code:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="100"/>
    <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="executor-task-"/>
    <property name="threadGroupName" value="executor-tasks"/>
</bean>
<bean id="taskScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
    <property name="poolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="scheduled-task-"/>
    <property name="threadGroupName" value="scheduled-tasks"/>
</bean>
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" scheduler="taskScheduler"/>
```

Comment: Explicitly configure the `TaskExecutor` that allows you to set the `threadGroupName` and `threadNamePrefix` properties.

Comment: I've tried this:
`<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="2"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="25"/>
        <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="scheduled-task"/>
        <property name="threadGroupName" value="scheduled-tasks-tg"/>
    </bean>
    <task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"/>`
but it's not working.

Comment: Please add the code to your question instead of a comment. That way it remains readable. Make sure you wired the executor to the `task:annotation-driven`.

Comment: And what doesn't work in this case? Don't see antyhing strange, looks like it should work.

Comment: Doh. You need a `TheadPoolTaskScheduler` ... My mistake. The `executor` is for `@Async` not for `@Scheduled`.

Comment: Wonderful, this worked. Please write an answer so I can accept it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to be able to specify a prefix or group name you have to configure a `TaskScheduler` (for `@Scheduled`) or a `TaskExecutor` (for `@Async`) yourself. If you do that you can set the `threadGroupName` and `threadNamePrefix` properties to customize the names to the thread.

```
<bean id="taskScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="2"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25"/>
    <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="scheduled-task"/>
    <property name="threadGroupName" value="scheduled-tasks-tg"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have multiple `@Scheduled` annotated tasks in my application.  In the above approach for all the tasks, the same prefix will be used.  I would prefer to give different prefixes for each task.  Is it possible?

Comment: Hi Manu:-  I have the same scenario , where I have multiple @Scheduled annotation. Can you please share your experience/solution on the same